# Faster parsing with Python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to parse data from one web page. This web page allows you (according to robots.txt) to send 2000 requests per minute.

The problem is that everything I tried is too slow. The response of this server is quite quick.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

import datetime
import lxml.html as lh
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('products.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

def update(url):

    html = requests.get(url).content #  3 seconds 

    doc = lh.parse(html) # almost 12 seconds (with commented line below)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html) # almost 12 seconds (with commented line above)

pool = Pool(10)

for line in lines[0:100]:
    pool.apply_async(update, args=(line[:-1],))

pool.close()

now = datetime.datetime.now()
pool.join()
print datetime.datetime.now() - now
```

As I commented into the code - when I try to do just `html = requests.get(url)` for 100 urls, the time is great - under 3 seconds.

The problem is when I want to use some parser - the preprocessing of the html costs about 10 seconds and more which is too much.

What would you recommend me to lower the time?

EDIT: I tried to use `SoupStrainer` - it is slightly faster but nothing too much noticeable - 9 seconds.

```
html = requests.get(url).content

product = SoupStrainer('div',{'class': ['shopspr','bottom']})

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml', parse_only=product)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need to extract from the pages, perhaps you don't need the full DOM. Perhaps you could get away with `HTMLParser`(`html.parser` in Python3). It should be faster.

I would decouple getting the pages from parsing the pages, e.g. two Pools, one is getting the pages and filling a queue, where the other pool is getting pages from the queue and parsing them. This would use the available resources slightly better, but it wont be a big speed up. As a side effect should the server start serving pages with a bigger delay, you could still keep the workers busy with a big queue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I work with Python 2.7, is there some alternative to HTMLParser from Python 3? Thanks

Comment: @Milan, `HTMLParser` is 2.7, it was renamed to `html.parser` in python 3

Comment: @Milan, also the separation of IO from Processing might be worthwhile, and it isn't even a big effort considering you already do multiprocessing